# Java - JSON output is not expected as what console suggests

Tags: java, json, spring, jersey

I'm new to Java and writing APIs.

I basically have two things: a HashMap called `db` that should be returned as a JSON and an ArrayList called `defaultParameters`. Basically what the application does are the following:

`db` basically contains an array of objects of key-value pairs that should be returned as a JSON when a user makes a GET request to this address.

`defaultParameters` is basically a list of default key-value pairs. If there is no key-value pair within that object, then that object takes in that default key-value pair.

I was able to get it to display on the console, but for some reason, the updated values are not appearing in the JSON when I do the get request.

Here are the relevant code snippets:

```java
    private static ArrayList<Item> DB = new ArrayList<>();
    private static HashMap<String, String> defaultValues = new HashMap<>();
    private void updateAllItems(){
        for(Item item : DB){
            for(Map.Entry entry : defaultValues.entrySet()){
                String currentField = (String) entry.getKey();
                String currentValue = (String) entry.getValue();
                item.addField(currentField, currentValue);
            }
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getAllItems() {
        updateAllItems();
        for(Item item : DB){
            // Test code that I added 
            item.printItem();
        }
        return Response.ok(DB).build();
    }
```

Snippets of the Item class

```java
public class Item {

    private HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<>();

    public void addField(String key, String value){
        item.put(key, value);
    }

    public void printItem(){
        for(Map.Entry entry : item.entrySet()){
            String currentField = (String) entry.getKey();
            String currentValue = (String) entry.getValue();
            System.out.println(currentField + ": " + currentValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Doing the `POST` request and doing the `GET` request yields the following:

On the console (Something: notsomething) is new:

```
seller: Mrs. Fields
price: 49.99
title: Cookies
category: 42
something: notsomething
```

The JSON response however:

```
[{"category":"42","seller":"Mrs. Fields","price":"49.99","title":"Cookies"}]
```

The JSON is missing the new key-value pair that the console has. I'm trying to have the JSON reflect what the console is doing. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: At what point is  private static HashMap<String, String> defaultValues = new HashMap<>(); initialized with entries.From your code snippet its remains empty in updateAllItems() unless its initialized elsewhere

Comment: `defaultValues` doesn't get initialized until the first `POST` request is made that updates the `defaultValues`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after some thinking, I figured out what to do.

I changed my code from

```java
public class Item {
```

to

```java
public class Item extends HashMap<String, String> {
```

and removed

```java
private HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<>();
```

which means I had to change `item` to `this`. I figured since that I'm going to be using each instance as a hashmap, I may as well extend the hashmap that will change the instance of the item too.

Thanks for everyone's help. The comment gave me some more insight of what I was trying to do which led to a solution.